# mysql replication slave (13 "Permission denied") but mysql command works

Tags: mysql, mariadb, database-replication

I set up replication on mysql (MariaDB). This is the output of `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` on slave machine.

```
Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'slaveuser@127.0.0.1:33061' - retry-time: 10  maximum-retries: 86400  message: Can't connect to MySQL
server on '127.0.0.1' (13 "Permission denied")
Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for the slave I/O thread to update it
```

I forwarded the port `33061` on the slave machine to `3306` on the master machine using ssh tunneling:

```
ssh -L 33061:localhost:3306 tunneluser@[IP] -f -N
```

Now I can successfully connect to the master mysql using this command:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u slaveuser -P 33061 -p

Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 1616
Server version: 10.3.16-MariaDB-log MariaDB Server

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

I also opened port 33061 on `firewalld` for `mysql` service:

```
firewall-cmd --info-service=mysql

mysql
  ports: 3306/tcp 33061/tcp
  protocols:
  source-ports:
  modules:
  destination:
```

What seems to be the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: Who were you running as?

Comment: I run `mysql -h...` command as a regular user with sudo privileges.

Comment: Did the slave previously work?  If yes, then what changed?  If no, then was the slave installed via sudo?

Comment: Yes. The slave worked normally before I close 3306 port (because it was bad practice) and use ssh tunneling via `ssh -L 33061:localhost:3306 tunneluser@[IP] -f -N`